# Recovering linux boot entries in a UEFI dual boot setting

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader

I have recently upgraded my MSI GS63VR-6RF with a 32 GB RAM. Upon upgrade, I noticed that the system automatically boots to my windows 10 partition instead of the typical `systemd-boot` screen where I can choose whether to use Arch Linux or Windows 10.

My first approach was to use the bootable Arch linux installer to access my arch partition. Provided that `sda2` is my EFI boot, `sda6` is my linux root, and `sda7` is my swap, here are what I did:

1. create the swap

   swapon /dev/sda7
2. mount partitions

   mount /dev/sda6 /mnt

   mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
3. switch to arch root on system

   arch-chroot /mnt
4. install bootloader

   bootctl --path=/boot install
5. unmount and reboot

However, the system cannot still detect my arch linux partition. Any help is greatly welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do `bootctl` and `bootctl list` say? Maybe the EFI variables have been overwritten. What does `efibootmgr` print?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, Windows saw a hardware change, did a scan, and reverted its bootloader config.

Have you tried `# bootctl --path=esp install` (per your initial config) again? Have you checked the efi folders and made sure the Arch entry was there?

Note reply:

> What do bootctl and bootctl list say? Maybe the EFI variables have been overwritten. What does efibootmgr print? – Johan Myréen 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

Change boot order? It should be an intuitive and easy fix; worked flawlessly on my once multi-booted Samsung NP300E4C.